# Setup for host and vm ,vm to vm connection

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

How do I setup network of my oracle virtual box so that below possibility is achieved

Setup :

1)Oracle virtual box is setup on windows host

2)Virtual box has two vm's (Vm1,Vm2)

Goal:

1)Host should be able to ping both Vm's and vice versa

2)Vm1 should be able to ping vm2 and vice versa .

Comment: One way - set the network adopters on VM1 and VM2 as host only.

Comment: will vm1 and vm2 be able to ping each other and will the host be able to ping both vm's with this ?